# Jquery/CSS effect not working on all versions of Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have exausted every avenue including ensuring chrome is up to date, allows javascript, cookies and cache was cleared with no luck.

I am using this effect - http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index6.html 
on this page http://sor.jaffewebsites.com.au/our-classes/
But it is only working on some users Chrome and not others.
If it is working the image is shrinking on hover, for those who it is not working for the image is no shrinking causing it to sit on the figcaption.

Comment: `But it is only working on some users Chrome` - is there any similarity with the users it's not working with? Chrome version? Operating System? installed extensions?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I didn't think factors such as OS would affect this type of content. The version the reported to me is the latest - however I have the latest as well and it works fine for me? Could this be related ? 
http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: No - I don't even have java installed and it works fine for me

Comment: the people who it doesn't work for ... does it work in the other site for them>

Comment: No neither of the included links are working which made me think it isnt a problem with the website specifically

Answer (score 0):

If you guys have notice the chrome error console then you can find below error.
So may be due to this its not working in some browser.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined toucheffect.js